# How to filter eclipse rcp key bindings as ESC key?

Tags: java, event-handling, eclipse-rcp

I have some trouble to select combo item from `AutoCompleteField`.

When I begin to write into combo, some proposals are displayed with a pop-up dialog. If I select an item and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this choice is kept by combo: this is the common behavior.

If a key binding exists on <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the handler is activated, but the pop-up dialog is never notified from this event. The same does not occur with the {ESC} key !

I think there is a way to filter key as <kbd>Esc</kbd> one to bypass key bindings, anybody knows a way to do that?

I'm using eclipse RCP 3.4.2 on Fedora.

It has the same behavior with eclipse RCP 3.4.2 and 3.6.2 on Windows.

### Workaround

I have wrote a specific `AutoCompleteField`, then I add an `IContentProposalListener2` on the `ContentProposalAdapter` to disable the key bindings context when pop-up dialog opens and to restore it when it is closed.

This is not a satisfactory solution because the chain of responsibility for activating the context is broken.

Comment: I've found a workaround that is not satisfactory.